# Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0'

Tags: windows

Can anyone help me with my problem?

I'm using a windows8 OS and after the last windows update,and i think it last week my visual basic 2010 Express wont open if I open it it shows an error Message like this.but the program worked perfectly before the update. What should I do?

> Could not load file or assembly'PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0,
>   Culture=nuetral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of itsdependencies.
>   The System cannont find file specified

Comment: There is a 0 missing from the version number.  And "neutral" is not spelled correctly.  Is that you being sloppy with your question or with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Install all available updates for Windows and Visual Studio and reboot.
It should help.

Comment: my windows update is up to date...and i think it may be the cause of the problem after the update few days ago i cant open it anymore.. 


btw how can i update visual studio? 

thank you for your ressponse..

Comment: in that case - try to repair your VS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983433(v=vs.90).aspx